# Where is the /dist directory after a Travis build?

Tags: travis-ci, divshot

I am trying to deploy an AngularJS app onto a Divshot hosting through Travis CI.

This app contains a `/dist` directory which is:

- where the result of the Grunt build goes (as it does in local)
- `.gitignore`d, therefore not pushed (Travis has to rebuild it)
- set as the Divshot app's root directory

Travis installs deps and runs the build nicely, thanks to this `.travis.yml` file:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
- '0.10'

install:
  - "npm install"
  - "gem install compass"
  - "bower install"

script:
  - "grunt build"

deploy:
  provider: divshot
  environment:
    master: development
  api_key:
    secure: ...
  skin_cleanup: true
```

But when it comes to the deployment, Travis says:

```
Error: Your app's root directory does not exists.
```

It's actually a message from `divshot-cli` because the `/dist` dir does not exist. I get the exact same message when I do a `divshot push` in local after having removed the `/dist` dir.

Here is a build which cannot deploy: https://travis-ci.org/damrem/anm-client/builds/35582994

**How come the `/dist` dir does not exist on the Travis VM after install & building run OK?**

Notes:

- I tried to replace the `script` step by a `before_deploy` step, but the problem remains (build #13).
- If I push a pre-existing `/dist` folder with an `index.html` in it, it deploys nicely (https://travis-ci.org/damrem/anm-client/builds/35583904)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this might be caused by a typo. At the bottom you have `skin_cleanup: true` when it should be `skip_cleanup: true`. If skip cleanup isn't turned on Travis will "reset" the code to the exact state of git checkout before running deploy.